How can i create one global variable for all clients in multiplier-game (Unity + NetCode)?
I'm just learning how to use NetCode.
I need to use ONE variable (string for example) for all clients and host/server. When new client connected to server first time, it can read/write this variable. The main problem is that evry user in Unity multiplier has own build with own instances of the classes. Work with Unity + NetCode.
I try using ServerRpc/ClientRpc and NetworkVariable, but I don't understand much about it.

have a server call that returns a value to all clients?

@BugFinder I'm not sure, since every client (and server) has a copy of all the game scripts. I do not know how to change the value only on the server, and then send it to all clients.

Well the server knows whether its a server. And the clients can ask for the value and get the results sent back.   Id suggest looking over the netcode documentation

I try using ServerRpc/ClientRpc and NetworkVariable, but I don't understand much about it. then I would suggest to go through some tutorials about that topic. Once you understand them it is quite straightforward ... NetworkVariable actually has a quite complete example for your exact use case I suppose .. the only thing missing is the according ServerRPC to allow clients to also set the value of the NetworkVariable via the server
